# Why isn't conversion of Decimal.MaxValue between Single and Decimal transitive?

Tags: c#

If I try and convert `Decimal.MaxValue` from `Decimal` to `Single` and back again, the conversion fails with an `OverflowException`:

```
Convert.ToDecimal(Convert.ToSingle(Decimal.MaxValue))
// '...' threw an exception of type 'System.OverflowException'
//     base: {"Value was either too large or too small for a Decimal."}
```

What gives? Surely the value of `Decimal.MaxValue` as a `Single` should be a valid `Decimal` value?

I understand that the differences between `Single` and `Decimal` and expect a loss of *precision* converting from `Decimal` to `Single` but as `Single.MaxValue` is greater than `Decimal.MaxValue` it doesn't make sense that the "Value was either too large or too small for Decimal". If you think that does make sense please explain why in an answer.

Additionally,

```
Convert.ToSingle(Decimal.MaxValue)
// 7.92281625E+28
```

so there is no problem converting this number to a `Single`.

Comment: Are you confusing `double` and `decimal`? `Decimal.MaxValue` is 79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335, `Single.MaxValue` is 3.402823e38.

Comment: @DStanley No it's not.  `var s = Convert.ToSingle(Decimal.MaxValue);` runs just fine.

Comment: Note that `float` will only have an approximation of the decimal value and it looks like the approximation is larger.

Comment: @juharr Actually the approximation is smaller (79,228,160,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 versus 79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're making an incorrect assumption:

> Surely the value of `Decimal.MaxValue` as a `Single` should be a valid
>   `Decimal` value?

The value of `Decimal.MaxValue` is `79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335`. A `float` can't represent anywhere near that level of precision, so when you convert the `decimal` value to a `float` you end up with an approximation.

In this case the `float` is represented internally as `2^96`. This turns out to be a pretty good approximation -- `79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,336` -- but take note of that last digit.

The value of the `float` is larger than `Decimal.MaxValue`, which is why your attempt to convert it back into a `decimal` fails.

(The .NET framework doesn't offer much help when trying to diagnose these kind of problems. It'll always display a pre-rounded value for the `float` -- `7.92281625E+28` or similar -- and never the full approximation that it's using internally.)

Comment: Yes. `Convert.ToSingle` performs rounding to the nearest.

Comment: Then why is it still not possible to do the following?

`float first = (float)decimal.MaxValue - 100;`

`decimal second = (decimal)first;`